# Read data in text file using batch file and use these values to execute multiple commands

Tags: maven, batch-file, text-files

First of all I am very new to batch scripting excuse for any mistakes. I have a batch script with below content:

```
d:
cd D:\eclipse-java-luna-SR1-win32-x86_64\eclipse\workspace\Automation
call mvn clean
IF NOT EXIST counter.txt 
(
  echo.>"counter.txt"
  call mvn install
  call mvn compiler:compile
  call mvn eclipse:eclipse
)
call mvn -Dtestfile=dictionary\animalReport\animalColor.xml test
pause
```

Here I am hard-coded `'animalColor.xml'`.

Instead of this I need to have multiple .xml names in a text file. I need to read and execute "`mvn -Dtestfile=`" command for each value.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work, please check the command "for" in batch

```
 for /f   %%i in ('type abc.txt') do (
        call mvn -Dtestfile=dictionary\animalReport\%%i test
        )
```

This code should iterate through each line of abc.txt. So the text file should like this

```
animalColour.txt
humancolor.txt
```

Comment: Improve your code with `for /f "tokens=* delims="  %%i ...` and with `call mvn -Dtestfile="dictionary\animalReport\%%~i" test`. Here `"tokens=* delims="` to accept spaces in file names like `animal Colour.xml` and `%%~i` to accept quoted file names like `"animal Colour.xml"`

Answer (score 0):

what about
echo run start (or other random command) >>%RANDOM%.TXT

```batch
@echo off&color 2
:program
echo enter commands here>>%TEXT%
call %TEXT%
goto x

:X
set text=%RANDOM%>TXT
goto program





tho u may also want 2               
del /Q *.TXT                   
in current directory of course
```